# Core data multi thread issue

Tags: uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm experiencing some issues with core-data, I think I'm missing something and I need some help.

I have implemented a simple table view which is loading with a fetched result controller a few objects from core data. I enabled the "editing" methods to delete a row and I successfully managed to delete the relative object in core data. The problem is: if I exit the table view and than I load it again (in simulator) for 3-4 seconds the deleted row is still there. If a load the table view after 3-4 seconds the list of items is correct.

This means to me that core data is waiting 3-4 seconds before saving and if I fetch the data during this time I get the wrong result. Is this possible?